# Pass by reference, child scope only?

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference

I have tried searching on this, since I bet there are questions like these already. However I only get topics about passing by reference in a global setting.

I was wondering about the following;

---

Variable scope is in this function only and will be cleaned when leaving the scope

```
void Class::DoSomething(){
    String s = "localVariable"; 

    cout << s;
}
```

If I would change the prior function in the following two functions. Would the scope be also only in the parent function and will the variable memory be freed or do I have to call free()?

```
void Class::DoSomethingParent(){
    String s = "localVariable"; //Local scope only

    //This function uses the reference of my variable s. 
    Class::DoSomethingChild(s);

    //Does the prior function do anything special because of the reference,
    //so I have to call free(s)?

    //Or does the variable still gets freed after leaving the scope of this function?
}
void Class::DoSomethingChild(String& value){
    cout << value;
}
```

Comment: You do not have to do anything special, `s` is in the scope of `DoSomethingParent` and will be destroyed once that function ends

Comment: There's no need to free something explicitly, `s` will be tidied automatically when the scope is left.

Comment: `s` is defined as a local variable. It doesn't matter that you send it by reference to another function. When it's scope ends, it's memory will be freed automatically, like any local variable.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I thought, but wanted to be sure about it! (Could you create an answer?)

Comment: note that if you do something like 'static String& t = value' within DoSomethingChild then you'll end up with undefined behaviour once DoSomethingParent has finished

Comment: @UKMonkey because value is a pointer to a memory address which will be freed out of scope and t still holds the pointer to the memory address?

Comment: @Sliver2009 correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects with an *Automatic Storage Duration* in C++ are essentially objects declared within a function block scope, that scope **owns** and **controls the lifetime** of such objects created therein. Example:

```
void function(){
   ....
   String s = "Some Data";
   someFuncByReference(s);
   ....
} //All objects of automatic storage duration owned by this scope are destroyed here...
```

Irrespective of whether you pass the object by reference or take the address of the object, and pass unto a function. The called function, `someFuncByReference` still doesn't control the lifetime of `s`, and should not destruct `s`<sup>1</sup>.

This applies to any "*function*", including, *non member-functions*, *member-functions* and *function specializations* produced by templates. Note that, this is not the same with *data members* of a class. The lifetimes of class data members are controlled by the constructor and destructor of that class.

---

<sup>1: However, if it does, it must create another one using *placement-new*.</sup>

Comment: Does this also hold for a Class Instance defined within a function. Like Class* classInstance = new Class(); Leaving the scope of the function automatically destroys the instance?

Comment: @Sliver2009 Yes, that's always true. Lookup the RAII principle.

Comment: @user0042 Thank you, I will look it up.

Comment: *Does this also hold for a Class Instance defined within a function. Like `Class* classInstance = new Class();`* Note that the memory that `classInstance` points to does not get freed when the scope ends.